# Installing 13.04 from USB causes a reboot hafway through

Tags: installation, 13.04, usb-drive

I recently installed 13.04 Raring Ringtail on a new, formatted USB flash drive, using the installer from http://pendrivelinux.com. To boot from it, I rearranged the boot order in BIOS. The system messes around a bit, then shows "Try Ubuntu" and"Install Ubuntu" (or words to that effect). Running Ubuntu from the USB - that is, clicking "Try Ubuntu" - works fine. The problem arises when I try to install.

To simplify things, here's a link:
[How to Install Ubuntu 13.04 Raring Ringtail](http://web.archive.org/web/20130929210002/http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-install-ubuntu-13-04-raring-ringtail)

These instructions are very clear, except on what to do when that doesn't happen.

Everything is fine until part 3. I want to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7, so I leave that box checked, and click "Continue". This *always* causes the computer to restart. I also discovered that if, instead of leaving the first box checked, I click on it (and it stays ticked), the "Continue" option turns into "Restart to Continue".

When the computer has restarted, everything s exactly as it was before. Nothing is installed, Windows runs fine, and going back to the Ubuntu installer shows that nothing has changed there, either: it still restarts the computer.

I have searched around on Google; the only links that look promising are on the ubuntuforum.org, which is currently offline, apparently due to a security breach.

I think this is all of the relevant (and irrelevant!) soft and hardware info:

```
OS Name Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium
Version 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
Other OS Description    Not Available
OS Manufacturer Microsoft Corporation
System Name HENRIKOLDCORN
System Manufacturer Hewlett-Packard
System Model    HP Pavilion dv6 Notebook PC
System Type x64-based PC
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2450M CPU @ 2.50GHz, 2501 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS Version/Date   Hewlett-Packard F.1A, 22/06/2012
SMBIOS Version  2.7
Windows Directory   C:\Windows
System Directory    C:\Windows\system32
Boot Device \Device\HarddiskVolume1
Locale  United Kingdom
Hardware Abstraction Layer  Version = "6.1.7601.17514"
User Name   HENRIKOLDCORN\Henrik
Time Zone   GMT Daylight Time
Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 8.00 GB
Total Physical Memory   7.95 GB
Available Physical Memory   4.09 GB
Total Virtual Memory    15.9 GB
Available Virtual Memory    11.2 GB
Page File Space 7.95 GB
Page File   C:\pagefile.sys
```

The USB flash drive is a new SanDisk 16 GB Cruzer Edge, that used to contain some rubbish from SanDisk about encryption software, that was deleted when I formatted the drive with Windows.

So, what am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Hello, try to follow steps from this video: `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qBCHsgry2RQ`

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a HP and Windows 7 is usually installed in BIOS mode even if motherboard also is UEFI, you have used all 4 primary partitions. 
Most users with HP backup the HP-Tools partition as it is small and also can be redownloaded from HP. That gives you an available primary partition to use as an extended partition which can hold many logical partitions to use for Linux.

Also make sure you have not hibernated Windows.

Best to use Windows to shrink the Windows main install as the HP-Tools will not give enough space for installing Ubuntu. And reboot Windows so it can run its chkdsk and make its repairs due to its new size. Then you can install into the free space automatically or use manual partitioning to create your own partitions.

Other issues that probably do not apply.
Issues that only sometimes cause problems are RAID often from Intel SRT or Ultrabook type systems. Users who have tried to use Windows to create new partitions and drive is converted to dynamic partitions which do not work with Linux. Or a drive that was gpt and Windows converts back to MBR(msdos) but leaves gpt backup data on drive creating confusion on which partition type drive really is.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problems with 13.04 as well. Found it easier to install 12.04 which is rock stable then do a distribution upgrade from there.